# Rigorous proof of the properties of functions, limits, and relation to sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

This is all one big problem that builds on itself- meaning I **cannot use results from later parts in parts before them.** On the same token, I can totally use previous results in my proof of later ones. Whenever possible, which should be most of them from what I can gather, I would like to do delta/epsilon proofs.

Let f: $\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and have the property that f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y) for each x and y in $\mathbb{R}$.

a) Show that f(nx) = nf(x) and that $f(\frac xn) = \frac {f(x)}{n}$ for each $n \epsilon \mathbb{N}$ and $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

b) Show that f(0) = 0 and f(-x) = -f(x) for each $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

c) Show that if f has a limit at some $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$, then f has a limit at 0.

d) Show that if f has a limit at 0, then there is an a>0 and an M>0 such that |f(x)|

e) Show that if there is an a>0 and an M>0 such that |f(x)|

f) Show that if x has a limit for some $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$, then x has a limit at each $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$ and the limit as t approaches x of f(t) is f(x) for each $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

g) Show that if $x \epsilon \mathbb{Q}$, then f(r) = rf(1). Use this fact and the result above to prove that if f has a limit at some $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$,then f(x) = xf(1) for each $x \epsilon \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) proceed by induction. This is clear for $n=1$. Suppose it is true fir $n-1$ then

$f(nx)=f((n-1)x+x)=f((n-1)x)+f(x)=(n-1)f(x)+f(x)=nf(x)$.

Also $f(x)=f(n(\frac{x}{n}))=nf(\frac{x}{n})$ so $f(\frac{x}{n})=\frac{f(x)}{n}$.

(b) $f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)+f(0)=2f(0)$ so $f(0)=0$

$0=f(0)=f(x+(-x))=f(x)+f(-x)$ so $f(-x)=-f(x)$.

(c) Suppose $f$ has a limit at $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$. Call the limit $\ell$. Then if $\epsilon>0$ we can find $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|h|<\delta$ then $|f(h)-(\ell-f(x_{0}))|=|f(x_{0}+h)-\ell|<\epsilon$. So $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=\ell-f(x_{0})$.

(d) Since $f$ has a limit at $0$, which we will call \ell, then for $\epsilon>0$ there is $a>0$ such that if $0<|x|<a$ then $|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$. Hence $|f(x)|-|\ell|\le|f(x)-\ell|<\epsilon$ hence $|f(x)|<\epsilon+\ell$. Take $M=\epsilon+\ell$.

(e) Suppose that if $|x|<a$ then there is $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|<M$. Then let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$. Then if $|x-x_{0}|<a$ then $|f(x)-f(x_{0})|=|f(x-x_{0})|<M$ hence $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)=f(x_{0})$. $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary.

(f) Suppose $\lim_{h\to0}f(x_{0}+h)$ exists then

$\lim_{h\to0}f(x_{1}+h)=\lim_{h\to0}f(x_{0}+(x_{1}-x_{0})+h)=\lim_{h\to0}\big(f(x_{0}+h)+f(x_{1}-x_{0})\big)=f(x_{1}-x_{0})+\lim_{h\to0}f(x_{0}+h)$

so the limit exists everywhere. Since $f$ has a limit everywhere I may check the limit at $0$. Now I claim $\lim_{h\to0}f(h)=0$. Since the limit exists I may choose the sequence I wish to follow along. Note that

$f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{f(1)}{n}$ hence $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ which gives the limit we seek. As before this determines all other limits since $f(x+h)-f(x)=f(x)+f(h)-f(x)=f(h)$.

(g) We have already demonstrated this property for integers (by taking x=1 in a few previous exercises). Consider $r=\frac{p}{q}$ then

$f(\frac{p}{q})=\frac{f(p)}{q}=\frac{f(p\cdot 1)}{q}=\frac{pf(1)}{q}=\frac{p}{q}f(1)$.

By the previous problem since $f$ has a limit somewhere then it has a limit everywhere and $f(t)$ tends to $f(x)$ as $t$ tends to $x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. But arbitrarily close to $x$ we will have rationals. Hence arbitrarily close $f(r)=rf(1)$. So letting $r$ tends to $x$ along rationals we get that $f(x)=\lim_{r\to x}f(r)=\lim_{r\to x}rf(1)=xf(1)$.